# Responsive design to change the order and position of divs

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

This fiddle demonstrates my problem: http://jsfiddle.net/petebere/vbt7mhL5/

For screen width up to 800px the order of the divs should be as in the html structure.

However for screen width larger than 800px I would like

- the green div (panel-1) to stick to the top left side of the articles;
- the red div (panel-2) to stick to the top right side of the articles;

as shown on this image: http://s10.postimg.org/q12rv2ewp/flexbox.jpg

So far I have been able to use the 'display: flex' combined with 'order' property to move green and red div up, but I can't figure out how to move the green div to the left and red div to the right.

The HTML code:

```
<div class="header">

    <div class="menu-top">menu-top</div>

</div>    

<div class="content">

    <div class="article-1">article-1<br>This will be an article about some interesting topic.</div>
    <div class="article-2">article-2<br>This will be an article about some interesting topic.</div>
    <div class="panel-1">panel-1<br>This should be on left for screen width > 800px.<br>It should 'stick' to the side of the articles.</div>
    <div class="article-3">article-3<br>This will be an article about some interesting topic.</div>
    <div class="panel-2">panel-2<br>This should be on right for screen width > 800px.<br>It should 'stick' to side of the articles.</div>
    <div class="article-4">article-4<br>This will be an article about some interesting topic.</div>
    <div class="article-5">article-5<br>This will be an article about some interesting topic.</div>

</div>

<div class="footer">

    <div class="menu-bottom">menu-bottom</div>

</div>
```

CSS:

```
.header, .footer {
    width: 100%;
}

.menu-top, .menu-bottom {
    background-color: LightGray;
    text-align: center;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}

.panel-1 {
    background-color: ForestGreen;
    text-align: center;
}

.panel-2 {
    background-color: crimson;
    text-align: center;
}

.article-1 {
    background-color: LightSteelBlue;
}

.article-2 {
    background-color: PaleTurquoise;
}

.article-3 {
    background-color: LightBlue;
}

.article-4 {
    background-color: LightCyan;
}

.article-5 {
    background-color: PowderBlue;
}

@media screen and (min-width:801px) {
    .content {
        align-items: center;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:801px) {
    .article-1, .article-2, .article-3, .article-4, .article-5 {
        width: 400px;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:801px) {
    .panel-1 {
        order: -3;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:801px) {
    .panel-2 {
        order: -1;
    }
}

@media screen and (min-width:801px) {
    .article-1 {
        order: -2;
    }
}
```

Comment: are you able to use bootstrap for that?

Comment: I probably can. Although I haven't used it yet so that would mean a more profound change to the existing html and css structure. So at the moment I'm trying to figure our whether the desired solution can be implemented using clean html and css.

Comment: How much tweaking of the HTML is available? Ideally (and semantically) the articles should be in a separate wrapper. Then it gets *much* easier.

Comment: The HTML can be modified - no problems. We just can't figure out how to organise the individual divs and wrappers to achieve the desired layout.

Answer (score 1):

Please replace this CSS with your CSS It can be solve your issue.

also I have update you fiddle demo http://jsfiddle.net/vbt7mhL5/5/ .

Note:- add one more class (**item**) in your **item** list for set the width.

```
.header, .footer {
    width: 100%;
}

.menu-top, .menu-bottom {
    background-color: LightGray;
    text-align: center;
}

.content {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    text-align: center;
}

.panel-1 {
    background-color: ForestGreen;
    text-align: center;
}

.panel-2 {
    background-color: crimson;
    text-align: center;
}

.article-1 {
    background-color: LightSteelBlue;
}

.article-2 {
    background-color: PaleTurquoise;
}

.article-3 {
    background-color: LightBlue;
}

.article-4 {
    background-color: LightCyan;
}

.article-5 {
    background-color: PowderBlue;
}

@media screen and (min-width:801px) {
    .content {
        align-items: center;
    }
    .item{
       width: 33.33%
    }
    /*.article-1, .article-2, .article-3, .article-4, .article-5 {
        width: 400px;
    }*/
    .panel-1 {
        order: -3;
        position: absolute;
        top: 27px;
        left: 0;
    }
    .panel-2 {
        align-self: flex-end;
        order: -1;
        position: absolute;
        right: 3px;
        top: 27px;
    }
    .article-1 {
        /*order: -2;*/
    }
}
```

If you got your answer then accept my answer,so some one get easily correct answer.

Comment: The absolute positioning of the green and red side panels will not work as the height of the header will vary depending on the browser screen size or settings (e.g. font size).